# what package provides systemd-networkd in RHEL8?

Tags: linux, rhel

I am unable to find systemd-networkd package for RHEL 8. I tried yum provides and yum search but to no avail.

```
[ec2-user@server1 ~]$ sudo yum search systemd-networkd
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:33 ago on Mon 03 Feb 2020 08:16:21 UTC.
No matches found.
[ec2-user@server1 ~]$ sudo yum search systemd-resolved
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:43 ago on Mon 03 Feb 2020 08:16:21 UTC.
No matches found.
[ec2-user@server1 ~]$ sudo yum provides systemd-networkd
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:50 ago on Mon 03 Feb 2020 08:16:21 UTC.
Error: No Matches found

[ec2-user@server1 ~]$ sudo yum search systemd | grep networkd
Last metadata expiration check: 0:11:47 ago on Mon 03 Feb 2020 08:16:21 UTC.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `systemd-networkd` in RHEL 8. As per [RHBZ#1650342](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1650342), Red Hat treats `systemd-networkd` e.g. as not mature enough, it's said that it's somewhat poorly maintained upstream, it is missing a DBUS management interface and its configuration is incompatible to NetworkManager (RHEL's network configuration tool). A couple of further reasons are spread over the before mentioned bug report. However, some Fedora contributors are working on `systemd-networkd` for EPEL 8 at [RHBZ#1789146](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1789146).